# wondering how to write the python code for sentence capitalizer

Tags: python

I am currently doing a task but I am stuck at the moment, so here is the code so far I have written:

```
string = input('please enter a string: ')
s = []

def sentenceCapitalize(string):
    strn = string.split('. ')   #convert to a list
    for x in strn:
        y = x[0].upper()
        y += x[1:].lower()
        s.append(y)
        
    print('.'.join(s))

sentenceCapitalize(string)
```

*It only gets me the result as a list and period is disappeared*

Unexpected Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

Hello. My name is Joe. What is your name?

*And here is the question from the book:*

> Write a program with a function that accepts a string as an argument
> and returns a copy of the string with the first character of each
> sentence capitalized. For instance, if the argument is “hello. my name
> is Joe. what is your name?” the function should return the string
> “Hello. My name is Joe. What is your name?” The program should let the
> user enter a string and then pass it to the function. The modified
> string should be displayed.

Can you fix this solution? thanks.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-a-list-to-string/

Comment: `print('. '.join(s))`

Comment: @KingStone I know that but i need the period back as well. for example, its only give me Hello My name is Joe What is your name? without the dot. how can i do that?

Comment: @Nick but the expected output is 'hello. my name is Joe. what is your name' with dots only. while the join() method get me ' hello, my name is Joe. what is your name?' its get me both comma and dot.

Comment: The output of the `print('. '.join(s))`  is `Hello. My name is joe. What is your name?`

Comment: @Nick can you check my new edited question above? i just updated it... not  sure whats going on...

Comment: Your input has a comma `,` after `hello`, not a period `.` But you are also lowercasing all the remaining letters in the string so you should remove the `.lower()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main three errors you have in your code are:

- You convert to lower case the rest of the sentence, so for example Joe will become joe
- You `split` based on ('. '), but when concatenating back you `join` by ('.'), so you are missing the white space
- You need a regex split, to consider both `,` and `.`. In the regex you pass the two options separated by `|`, and for the case of dot you need to add before '' since '.' itself is an operator in regex. More about [Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Try this:

```
string = input('please enter a string: ')
s = []
import re

def sentenceCapitalize(string):
    strn = re.split(',|\.', string)   #convert to a list
    for x in strn:
        y = x[0].upper()
        y += x[1:]
        s.append(y)
        
    print('.'.join(s))

sentenceCapitalize(string)
```

Comment: thanks! i didn't notice there is a name is inside it which is need to be capitalized. this is very important to take note.

Comment: @MINO actually there is still one part pending, I will edit the code, since the comma is not used in the split. I am editing the code now

Comment: What happens when the string is `hello, my Name is Joe. what is your name?`. I assume `Name` stays as uppercase `N`

Answer (score 0):

One sentence solution:

```
print('. '.join([st[0].upper() + st[1:] for st in string.split('. ')]))
```